# Exception occurring while connecting a C# client application to XSockets Server

Tags: c#, client, xsockets.net

I am using XSockets for having two way (web socket based) communication between an XSockets Server and an existing C# desktop client application.

I have integrated code in my existing client application for communicating with XSockets Server.

For now, XSocket Server starts as a separate console application. It starts fine with no problems.
Then I am using following pseudo code block in my C# client application:

```
    XSocketClient client = new XSocketClient("ws://127.0.0.1:4509/MyController", "*", false);      //Error occurs right on execution of this line

    client.Open();
```

Following is the Exception snapshot that throws out;

```
Exception of type 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' was thrown

Custom Message:  Failed to load exported interfaces in assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Source: XSockets.Plugin.Framework

Stack Trace:  at XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.SatifyImportsExports()

   at XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.Initialize()

   at XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport[T]()

Type:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Note: If I create a new C# windows form client project and try executing this code, it executes fine and connection is successfully made to the XSocket Server.
Means there is something disturbing from inside my existing client project.

What could the possible reason for this weird exception ? Any ideas? Thanks

Edit: I have noted that if I manually remove Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation DLL from my Bin folder, it raises same kind of exception but with a different custom message this time. I mean then the error is related to some other DLL (of my existing application) present in Bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem yesterday and solved it like so:

```
 Composable.ClearPluginFilters();
 Composable.AddPluginFilter("XSockets.*.dll");
```

This code was called just before I bootstrapped my application and started my server. I know the question is kinda old but if anyone else end up here aswell.

[Source from Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/xsocketsgroup/ExportException/xsocketsgroup/p5uBcg78DTE/UuuwaCC7GDsJ)

Answer (score 1):

Ok found answer to my own raised question.

There can be two things related to this issue:

1. *Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.dll* was causing problem from the Bin => Release/Debug folders. From Visual studio project references list, right clicked the *Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation* reference, clicked on Properties and set [Copy Local] property to false. XSocketsClient was now connecting successfully to the XSockets Server but some other logic of my existing application was still needing Enterprise Library which being Copy Local ==> false, was not coming available to the .Net Runtime, so it showed an Exception whenever Runtime was coming across those parts of code.
2. To resolve the later issue encountered because of removal of Enterprise Library reference, I added again Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation reference and also added one another DLL *Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll* and added its reference to my client application.

Now my client application connects fine to XSocket Server and also now no issue comes with the inclusion of Enterprise Library reference.

Seems like there are some things essential needed by Enterprise Library at runtime which lie in that second DLL.